# .NET remove inline event handler

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, event-handling

I got a little problem with adding and removing event handlers in Visual Basic.NET.
While this is in general rather easy, I need to remove a inline event handler. Question is if and how this works.

```
AddHandler object.ConnectionSuccessful, Sub()
                                            RemoveHandler object.ConnectionSuccessful, Me
                                        End Sub
```

This is the way how I tried it, it does not work. Now the question is how do I remove this inline event handler again if not this way? I found some cruel methods to remove all event handlers from a object but this is not what I want to do. I only want to remove this one single specific event handler.

I am aware that those problem disappear if I just use a normal function and the `AddressOf` operator. But in this case using the inline method is just more handy.

Anyone has a idea in this matter?

Comment: You can't.  You must use the AddressOf operator in this case and give up on the lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign your lambda to a variable, then it is possible to do this (assuming this sort-of inline structure is close to what you want). Note that you have to Type the lambda, in this case as `Action` in order to refer to itself from itself.

```
Module Module1

Event TestEvent As Action

Sub Main()

    Dim TestLamba As Action = Sub()
                                  Console.Write("Event!")
                                  RemoveHandler TestEvent, TestLamba
                              End Sub

    AddHandler TestEvent, TestLamba

    RaiseEvent TestEvent()

    RaiseEvent TestEvent()

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

End Module
```

If you run this test console app above, you'll see that the event is fired twice, but "Event!" is only written to the console once.